# aggregate not found in the event store

Tags: java, axon

I am trying to add data using CQRS framework AXON. But while hitting the API(used to add an order). I am getting the below error:-

```
Command 'com.cqrs.order.commands.CreateOrderCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateNotFoundException(The aggregate was not found in the event store)
```

But i already have an Aggregate in my code(OrderAggregate.Java).

The Full code can be found at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/OrderManagementSystem

API to add Order - http://localhost:8080/confirmOrder

**Request Body:-**

```
{
    "studentName":"Sunny Khan"
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where am i doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For other readers, let me share the Aggregate you've created in your repository:

```
@Aggregate
public class OrderAggregate {
    public OrderAggregate(OrderRepositoryData orderRepositoryData) {
        this.orderRepositoryData = orderRepositoryData;
    }

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private Integer orderId;

    private OrderRepositoryData orderRepositoryData;

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(CreateOrderCommand command) {
        apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(command.getOrderId()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderCreatedEvent event) {
        this.orderId=event.getOrderId();
        Order order=new Order("Order New");
        orderRepositoryData.save(order);
    }

    protected OrderAggregate() {
        // Required by Axon to build a default Aggregate prior to Event Sourcing
    }

}
```

There are several things you can remove entirely from this Aggregate, which are:

1. The `OrderRepositoryData`
2. The `OrderAggregate` constructor which sets the `OrderRepositoryData`
3. The manually saving of an `Order` in the `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated function

What you're doing here is mixing the Command Model's concern of making decisions with creating a queryable `Order` for the Query Model. It would be better to remove this logic entirely from an Aggregate (the Command Model in your example) and move this to an Event Handling Component.

This is however not the culprit for the `AggregateNotFoundException` you're receiving.
What you've missed is to make the `CreateOrderCommand` command handler a constructor.

The `CreateOrderCommand` will create an Order, as it's name already suggests.
Hence, it should be handled by a constructor rather than a regular method.
So, instead of this:

```
    @CommandHandler
    public *void* handle(CreateOrderCommand command) {
        apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(command.getOrderId()));
    }
```

You should be doing this:

```
@CommandHandler
public OrderAggregate(CreateOrderCommand command) {
    apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(command.getOrderId()));
}
```

Hope this helps you out @Sunny!

Comment: I did not understand what did u mean by - The CreateOrderCommand will create an Order, as it's name already suggests. Hence, it should be handled by a constructor rather than a regular method:

Comment: The Option that u have suggested is not working as apply() method return null and not an Object.

Comment: Your sample has a `CreateOrderCommand` handler on a `public void handle(...){...}` method. Axon Framework however requires __an existing__ Aggregate to be able to handle a command on it. You however did not provide __any__ command handler to instantiate the aggregate. 

If you'd adjust the current `CreateOrderCommand` handler to be an constructor, I'd assume it should work - the `AggregateLifecycle#apply(Object...)` doesn't need to return anything.

Maybe the reference guide makes it clearer: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/aggregate

Comment: @Steven, your comment that begins "Your sample has..." should be incorporated into the answer. This comment resolved my problem: I had a `void` on the constructor. Newbie error. Thanks much, man.

Comment: Good suggestion @JonathanM, I've updated the reply a little to be more specific on this.

Answer (score 1):

aggregate not found in the event store

The main reason for this exception is, When the axon is trying to save the aggregate it should create the aggragate first.

```
@CommandHandler
public OrderAggregate(CreateOrderCommand command) {
    apply(new OrderCreatedEvent(command.getOrderId()));
}
```

Also in this way ur

private OrderRepositoryData orderRepositoryData;

won't be initialized, so autowired the orderRepositoryData also.

```
@Autowired
private OrderRepositoryData orderRepositoryData;
```

For the successive events you should use same **OrderId** ,else also it will throw

handleThrowable(java.lang.Throwable,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateNotFoundException: The aggregate was not found in the event store
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingRepository.doLoadWithLock(EventSourcingRepository.java:122)

Comment: Please avoid Emaratech specific code on Open forums.